# How to rename all columns by adding a prefix to them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I have a pandas dataframe `df` with 24 columns, named: `'0.0'`, `'1.0'`, `'2.0'`, ..., `'23.0'`.

Is there a way I could add `'period_'` before each of them, and the desired column names will be `'period_0'`, `'period_1'`, `'period_2'`, ..., `'period_23'`?

Answer (score 2):

Although I would probably do it like [@Sreeram TP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7896849/sreeram-tp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479540/6045800), here is another option:

```
df.columns = df.add_prefix('period_').columns.str[:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

To rename like you wanted,

```
df.columns = [f"period_{int(col)}" for col in df.columns]
```

OR

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: f"period_{int(x)}", inplace=True)
```